# Stream Zip files: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 0 but got 419 bytes)

Tags: java, java-stream, zip

I have a web service processing contents of ZIP files which I receive from a network source and stream back to a network target on the fly. This works great for many about 60% of my test files, but 40% of them can't be processed, because `zipEntry.getSize()` returns `-1` as the file size of all zip entries.

Below you can see two java tests streaming contents from a source zip to a target zip. The first one accepts any `InputStream` as a source (which is what I need, as I get my data directly from the network) and fails processing zip entries with unknown (`-1`) size.

The second test knows how to handle entries with unknown (`-1`) size, but can only handle streams originating from a local file (which is not what I need - it's only here to proof, that the zip files in question are not corrupt).

There's a lot of example online for handling local zip files - but very few about dealing with network streams, which is why I have a very hard time finding a solution to this.

The error thrown by the first example is `Stream Zip files: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 0 but got 419 bytes)`

Here's my code:

```
package de.ftk.threemf.mesh;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.zip.*;

@Slf4j
public class ZipStreamTests {

    @Test
    public void generalizedStreamZipTest() throws IOException {
        Path path = Path.of("testdata/brokenzip/trex.3mf");
        InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(path);
        OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(Path.of("testoutput/ziptest.3mf"));

        ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(in);
        ZipEntry zipEntry;

        CheckedOutputStream checkedOutputStream = new CheckedOutputStream(out, new Adler32());
        ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(checkedOutputStream);

        while ((zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            log.info("zip file contains: {} modified on {}", zipEntry.getName(), new Date(zipEntry.getTime()));
            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
            log.info("expecting " + zipEntry.getSize() + " bytes");
            IOUtils.copy(zipInputStream, zipOutputStream);
            zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
            zipInputStream.closeEntry();
        }
        zipInputStream.close();
        zipOutputStream.finish();
        zipOutputStream.close();
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void fileStreamZipTest() throws IOException {
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("testdata/brokenzip/trex.3mf");
        final ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("testoutput/ziptest.3mf"));
        for (Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> e = zipFile.entries(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) {
            ZipEntry entryIn = e.nextElement();
            log.info("zip file contains: {} modified on {}", entryIn.getName(), new Date(entryIn.getTime()));
            ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(entryIn.getName());
            log.info("expecting " + zipEntry.getSize() + " bytes");
            zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
            InputStream is = zipFile.getInputStream(entryIn);
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = (is.read(buf))) > 0) {
                zos.write(buf);
            }
            zos.closeEntry();
        }
        zos.close();
    }

}
```

Hint: A `3MF` file is a `ZIP` file containing 3D-Models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even as recent as jdk-1.8.0_341, there still seems to be a [bug related to ZIP64](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8298530) in `ZipInputStream`.

It triggers under these conditions:

- File size and compressed size are under 4 GiB
- The local file header is ZIP64-encoded
- Actual file sizes are contained within a trailing data descriptor

`ZipInputStream` interprets the data descriptor as 32-bit despite the local file header being ZIP64 and therefore reads the file size incorrectly.  The culprit is here in the `readEnd()` method:

```
 if ((flag & 8) == 8) {
    /* "Data Descriptor" present */
    if (inf.getBytesWritten() > ZIP64_MAGICVAL ||
        inf.getBytesRead() > ZIP64_MAGICVAL) {
        // ZIP64 format
        ...
```

A bug fix should look something like this:

```
 if ((flag & 8) == 8) {
    /* "Data Descriptor" present */
    if (/* file header was ZIP64*/) {
        // ZIP64 format
        ...
```

The exception is only thrown once all of the file data is read and `ZipInputStream` attempts to close and verify the `ZipEntry` sizes, and CRC.  So the stream may be manually advanced using reflection to recover from the error.

```
ZipInputStream zipStream = ...;
zipStream.getNextEntry();
try {
    // Read file data
    zipStream.read(...);
} catch (ZipException e) {
    
    // Recover from error condition
    if (e.getMessage().startsWith("invalid entry size (expected 0 ")) {
        // Grab pushback stream
        Field inF = FilterInputStream.class.getDeclaredField("in"); inF.setAccessible(true);
        PushbackInputStream in = (PushbackInputStream) inF.get(zipStream);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) in.read(); // Read 8 extra bytes to compensate footer
        
        // Close the entry manually
        Field f = ZipInputStream.class.getDeclaredField("entryEOF");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(zipStream, true);
        f = ZipInputStream.class.getDeclaredField("entry");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(zipStream, null);
    } else {
        throw e;
    }
}
zipStream.getNextEntry(); // Continue as if exception hadn't occured
```

I created a complete packaged solution available at this repository.  There are also some sample ZIPs under test resources that will trigger the bug.

https://github.com/cjgriscom/ZipInputStreamPatch64

Answer (score 1):

This is related to ZIP64 subformat https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/zip-file-unreadable-cause-javautilzipzipexception-invalid-entry-size

Newer java7 and java8 releases have this fixed - jdk-1.8.0_91 is not ok, openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04 is ok.